# In a Blueimp jQuery file upload, setting dropzone to a div not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-file-upload, webusercontrol

I am trying to create a user control with this but having a problem while setting a Div as drop zone. As per api I should set jQuery object of target div and add preventDefault() method to avoid making whole document as drop area and make a selected area as drop zone.

Below code I am using to make it work

```
 function OnDocumentLoad(dropZoneElementId) {
        Initialize(dropZoneElementId);
          $(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

       });

      }

function Initialize(dropZoneElementId) {
$('#genericFileUploader').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    dropzone: dropZoneElementId,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is fine except "dropzone", it should be drop**Z**one.